# Vue CLI 3 / Webpack - Exclude files from build

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am trying to exclude some ttf files from my build as I don't need them.  What is the correct syntax to do this?

I tried adding the following to vue.config.js but no luck.

```
chainWebpack: config => {
  config.plugin('copy').tap((args) => [[{
    from :'node_modules/@mdi/font/fonts/',
    to: 'fonts',
    toType: 'dir',
    ignore: [
      'materialdesignicons*.ttf',
    ],
  }]]
 );
},
```

I delete the dist folder, then run 'npm run build'. I see the file(s) that should be omitted sitting in dist/fonts. Did I do something wrong with my paths? I don't see any relevant console output to go off of

Comment: Your config is malformed: (`to` is missing a colon). The `to` relative path specifies the destination under `dist`, so a value of `dist` would result in your font files copied to `dist/dist` (not `dist/font`). Maybe you're looking in the wrong dir?

Comment: Your config (corrected) works as expected for me. The `.ttf` files are not copied.

Comment: I corrected the post based on your suggestions, but that still did not work for me.  Is it because it's a node_modules portion and not something in src? In other words, is there different code that should be written to account for excluding parts of external dependencies?

Comment: No, it still works even for files copied from `node_modules`. Does that path actually exist from your project root? Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: Yep, it exists in the project root. CentOS

Comment: Ever figure this out?